# How to make a queue switches from FIFO mode to priority mode?

Tags: oop, algorithm, language-agnostic

I would like to implement a queue capable of operating both in the FIFO mode and in the priority mode. This is a message queue, and the priority is first of all based on the message type: for example, if the messages of `A` type have higher priority than the messages of the `B` type, as a consequence all messages of `A` type are dequeued first, and finally the messages of `B` type are dequeued.

**Priority mode:** my idea consists of using multiple queues, one for each type of message; in this way, I can manage a priority based on the message type: just take first the messages from the queue at a higher priority and progressively from lower priority queues.

**FIFO mode:** how to handle FIFO mode using multiple queues? In other words, the user does not see multiple queues, but it uses the queue as if it were a single queue, so that the messages leave the queue in the order they arrive when the priority mode is disabled. In order to achieve this second goal I have thought to use a further queue to manage the order of arrival of the types of messages: let me explain better with the following code snippet.

```
int NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES = 4;
int CAPACITY = 50;
Queue[] internalQueues = new Queue[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES];
Queue<int> queueIndexes = new Queue<int>(CAPACITY);

void Enqueue(object message)
{
    int index = ... // the destination queue (ie its index) is chosen according to the type of message.
    internalQueues[index].Enqueue(message);
    queueIndexes.Enqueue(index);
}

object Dequeue()
{
    if (fifo_mode_enabled)
    {
        // What is the next type that has been enqueued?
        int index = queueIndexes.Dequeue();

        return internalQueues[index].Dequeue();
    }

    if (priority_mode_enabled)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES; i++)
        {
            int currentQueueIndex = i;
            if (!internalQueues[currentQueueIndex].IsEmpty())
            {
                object result = internalQueues[currentQueueIndex].Dequeue();

                // The following statement is fundamental to a subsequent switching
                // from priority mode to FIFO mode: the messages that have not been
                // dequeued (since they had lower priority) remain in the order in
                // which they were queued.
                queueIndexes.RemoveFirstOccurrence(currentQueueIndex);

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about this idea?
Are there better or more simple implementations?

Answer (score 2):

Should work. However at a brief glance my thoughts are

a) Not thread safe and a lot of work to make it so. 
b) Not exception safe - i.e. an exception en queuing or De-queuing may leave an inconsistent state - maybe not a problem, e.g. if an exception was fatal, but maybe it is.
c) Possibly over complicated and fragile, although I do not know the context it's being used.

Personally unless I had profiled and had shown to have a performance problem, I would have one "container", and the priority mode would walk through the container looking for the next highest priority message - after all it's only 50 messages. I would almost certainly use a linked list. My next optimization would be to have one container with pointers to the first of each message type into that container, and update the pointer on de-queue of message.

Comment: Nice, it can't be done any simpler and with 50 messages probably any faster either.

Comment: I did not write the code for exception handling and thread safety because I was interested only evaluate the algorithm: of course, during the implementation, I will take into account the concurrent access by multiple threads and the exception handling. The capacity of 50 messages I have specified is just an example, since in fact I'm going to implement the algorithm in a generic class in which you can set the maximum capacity :-)

Comment: In that case the approach is about right, personally I would still simplify it for a first iteration, but I tend err on the  KISS side, I believe it's much easier to fix a broken "too simple" solution than fix a broken "too complex" solution. One thing that I do not like about the implementation is the returns in - they are a bit too buried.  IMHO a return value and single return is better in this case. Simple to implement with an else and far more readable. (I am not an evangelist of the  of the "One Exit Point" religion)

Comment: ..... Actually - reading it again the Dequeue has a problem if both values are false- should just use an "else" even if they cannot be. i.e. "if (fifo_mode_enabled) {...retval = something} else {...retval = something} return retVal"